# ASP.NET MVC: LessThan and GreaterThan Validation Two values compare?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, compare, data-annotations

`Compare` attribute that allows you to compare two inputs and display a validation message for Example  one Attribute Minprice and MaxPrice. MaxPrice Value grater than Minprice

### My Model

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceType ="Minprice"]
public double DealPrice { get; set; }

[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceType ="Please greater than MaxPrice")]
public double MaxPrice{ get; set; }
```

I am New in MVC idont know how to write Comapre validation in MVC.Can any one plsease Help me

Answer (score 2):

CompareAttribute: Provides an attribute that compares two properties. You may write your own dataannotations or you can use [foolproof validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @AliRiza.... no it is not working already am saw this..  Compare validation value grater than another validation

Comment: Did you install package foolproof?

Comment: @AliRiza... no ... how to install that package ..what is the requirment

Comment: .....now i knw littile bit understand Foolproof...thanks AliRiza...please halp me

Comment: Go [here](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) and read the documentation, it will definitely solve your problem